Performant way to create a PDF from many images on the shell
The easiest way to create a PDF from images is certainly to use ImageMagick:
convert --compress JPEG *.jpg out.pdf

The results are completely satisfactory: For each image there is a page in the PDF, the page size is set correctly based on the dimensions and resolution.
However, processing several hundred images into a PDF is incredibly slow, literally it takes hours (on a server with 16 GB RAM and 3 cores). As far as I understand, this is due to the way ImageMagick works, which is somehow that all images are decompressed into memory (with its own swapping to the hard disk), and only thereafter it creates a PDF from the multi-page raster image, compressing all images again (or not, depending on the parameters).
In this case, the images are already correct in themselves, they are JPEG, and embedded JPEG is permissible in PDF. All it would have to do is create the wrapping PDF, one page per image in the dimensions of the image, and paste the image onto it, without touching the image data. As a programmer, I quickly think that I can write a tool for this with a few libraries, but I wanted to ask first:
Can you achieve the same thing performantly using command line commands?

What operating system are you using? Do you happen to have LaTeX set up?

I am mostly using Ubuntu, but sometimes others, Debian or even SLES. There is no LaTeX yet, but I can install it, if it is the base for a better solution.

OK, but only different flavors of Linux then, nothing else. Please [edit] and add that to the question since the OS determines what tools we can expect, and what versions/implementations of those tools.

See the img2pdf answer (not the accepted answer) to duplicate question.

@meuh Not yet tested, but can you make an answer for it? It seems an interesting option.

yes, imagemagick is kind of infamous for being slow. Try graphicsmagick, which has a slightly nicer command line, but is otherwise pretty similar, but doesn't necessarily try to use the same amount of RAM for simple tasks like what you describe.
For rather fast conversions to PDF is the mutool/mupdf toolchain:
mutool draw -o outputfilename.pdf inputfilename.jpeg

but that is only fit to convert images individually. However, you could then mutool merge them. Something like this untested thing:
#!/usr/bin/zsh

setopt extendedglob

counter=1
mkdir target

for file in **/*.(#i)(jpg|jpeg); do
  mutool draw -o "target/$(printf '%03d' $counter).pdf" "${file}"
  counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
done
mutool -o joined.pdf target/*.pdf
rm -rf target

or so

I will take a look on it

The Python program img2pdf is very fast as it does not decode or uncompress jpeg images which pdf supports natively. You may have it available in a package for your distribution, or the link shows how to install it. If you have a lot of files, you can put the filenames in a file and use that list, instead of risking having an arglist that is too long. For example,
find . -name '*.jpg' -print0 | sort -z | img2pdf --from-file - -o /tmp/out.pdf

Filenames have to be separated by the nul char, not newline.
The sort -z puts the filenames in alphabetical order, as find will just list them from the entries in the directories. I tested this on a dozen files and compared it with convert and it used 7 times less cpu on my old computer.
